# ->where() is not working,any idea?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem. I had this code:

```
$model=VehicleModel::where('make_id','=',$make_id)->get();
return Response::json($model);
```

Its worked good,now I need to change something like that:

```
$maketable=$vehicletype.'_models';
$models=new VehicleModel;
$models->setTable($maketable);
$models->where('make_id',$make_id);
$model=$models->get();

return Response::json($model);
```

So,I added only just to set other table,and now the `->where` is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries):

```
$data = DB::table($maketable)->where('make_id', $make_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = DB::table($maketable)->whereMakeId($make_id)->get();
```